# Match everything except the digit and space in the very beginning

Tags: javascript, regex

The target string looks like a number followed by a space and then followed by one or more letters, e.g. `1 Foo` or `2 Foo bar`.

I can use `[^\d\s].+`, but it doesn't work for single letters, e.g. `3 A`.

What can be done here?

https://regexr.com/6io06

The workaround I use currently is to use replacing instead of matching.

```
from  \d\s(.+)
to    $1
```

But as a purist I prefer to use replacing if and only if we don't mean "replace something with nothing". When we need to replace something with nothing, I would prefer to use matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer using a regex replacement here:

```js
var input = ["1 Foo", "2 Foo Bar", "No Numbers Here"];
var output = input.map(x => x.replace(/^\d+ /, ""));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the square brackets. The square brackets alone indicate "any of this set", so you are matching either `\d` or `\s`. When you also add a `^` inside you are not indicating the beginning of the string, but you are negating the set. So, summing up, your regular expression means:

Match a single character that may be everything **except** a digit and a white space, then match everything.

If you remove the square brackets you will match `\d` followed by `\s`, and the `^` symbol will mean "beginning of the string".

```
/^\d\s(.+)/
```

Comment: Huh, isn't this what OP is using right now? OP explicitly said that he/she want to use pure matching instead of "find and replace with empty".

Comment: @Passerby I provided an explanation about why the regular expression wasn't working, other users already addressed the OP problem, so I think I'll leave my answer like this :)

Answer (score 1):

If I didn't misread your question, this might be what you want:
exclude capture the number and space at the beginning

https://regexr.com/6io1m

```
(?!^\d+)(?!\s+).*
```

This matches `1 Foo Bar` to `Foo Bar` and `3 A` to `A`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use replace. You can optionally match a digit and a space at the start of the string with `^(?:\d+ )?` and capture the rest of the line in group 1 that starts with a letter.

Note that if you want to use `\s` that is could also match a newline.

```
^(?:\d+ )?([A-Za-z].*)
```

[Regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/nUdhf0/1)

```js
const regex = /^(?:\d+ )?([A-Za-z].*)/;

["1 Foo", "2 Foo bar", "Test", "3 A", "-test-"]
.forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) console.log(m[1])
});
```